# How to pass route parameter in datatable function in laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables

This is my first post please pardon me.
I have a page named *messdata.blade.php* .I want to update the data-table of this page for every term id.

My route will be like this

> /admin/messdata/1,
>    /admin/messdata/2,
>   /admin/messdata/3.

Here 1,2,3 are the term id.I want to show the messdata in the data-table single.

[Screen shot of the datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UXNc.jpg)

But though I change the id my data-table stuck on the first id and doesn't change.

This is my **controller** code.

```
    public $termid=1;
    public function showmess($id)
    {
        $this->termid=$id;
        return view('foradmin.mess.messdata');
    }

    public function showmessdata()
    {
        $users= DB::select('select * from messes where  termno = :termno', ['termno' => $this->termid]);

        return Datatables::of($users)
        ->addColumn('action', function ($user) {
            return "<a href='/admin/perterminfo/$user->id' class='btn btn-xs btn-primary'></i><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open\"></span> OPEN</a>";
        })
        ->make(true);
    }
```

This my **data-table** code in **java-script**.

```
    <script>
        var table;
        $(function() {
            table=$('#users-table').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '{!! route('admin.messdatashow') !!}',
                columns: [
                    {data:'id',name:'id',searchable: false},
                    {data: 'messno', name: 'messno' },
                    {data: 'startat', name: 'startat',searchable: false },
                    {data: 'finishat', name: 'finishat',searchable: false },
                    {data:'messfee',name:'messfee', searchable: false},
                    {data:'extrafee',name:'extrafee', searchable: false},
                    {data:'fine',name:'fine',searchable: false},
                    {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false},
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is my **route**.

```
Route::get('admin/messdata/{id}','MessController@showmess')->name('admin.messdata');
Route::get('admin/messdatashow','MessController@showmessdata')->name('admin.messdatashow');
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Add your code. Now it's  not clear what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Sir, now I have given my code.Please take a look.

Comment: I'm not clear about your requirement, but what you're doing is not to be done I guess. You're changing the id from a route, then trying to catch that id related data from another route!

I think that's not how php works, the moment you hit the second route, the whole script is run and as you've set `$termid = 1`, this should always show data for id 1 and never change.
you must make the id change persistent between requests to show data properly.
I think what you're trying to do can be done directly via the second route by just adding the id param to it.

Comment: There are several terms. Every term has several messes.I want to update the data-table for every term id .For every term id the  data-table will show the different mess data.Please see the picture added above.

Comment: How can add parameter to the 2nd route? I have done it before but came out wrong.May be I don't know the proper way to pass parameter to the 2nd route.

Answer (score 0):

you can use $id = Request::segment(3) to get id from url

Comment: What is the segment(3), please explain?

Comment: Retrieve A Request URI Segment
$segment = Request::segment(segment_number);

Comment: public function showmessdata()
    {
        $id = Request::segment(3);
        $users= DB::select('select * from messes where  termno = :termno', ['termno' => $id]);

Comment: I have added like this.But the table says "No data available in table" .